# Enable/disable Daylight Savings Time through command line

Tags: command-line, time, date, timezone

Note: By "Disable" daylight savings time, I mean for the system clock to ignore any time changes for daylight savings time (ie, if DST is disabled, then the clock will not "spring forward" an hour in March and will not "fall back" an hour in November.

I am designing an Qt application to run on Ubuntu 18.04 and I need to be able to set system timezone, time and date.

For settings time and date, I can easily use [timedatectl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/timedatectl.1.html) to modify the system settings. However, this command does seem to be able to disable Daylight Savings Time. It does report whether DST is "Active" or not depending on the timezone and date, but you cannot disable/enable this settings.

On Windows, I had used [tzutil.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tzutil) to setting DST enabled or not using the dst_off flag. Is there are any equivalent to Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you want to use UTC, or your local time minus DST?

Comment: @glennjackman I want to be able to change to any Time Zone, but with the option of disabling/enabling DST depending on what the user selects

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to select a DST-enabled timezone (i.e. America/New_York) *and* "turn off" DST. I don't know what Microsoft does, but I wouldn't be surprised if they have re-implemented the Olson timezone database for their own purposes. You might want to ask this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Server Fault
3,495](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I will consult Stack Overflow. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What do exactly mean by "system clock"? If you mean the value returned by `gettimeofday()`, used for the timestamp of newly created files etc. (as opposed to the RTC/hardware/BIOS clock), it _never_ does DST adjustments.

Comment: We might be facing an XY problem, or based on the wording of the question I suspect that you may not understand the fundamentals of Unix's timestamp handling. Make sure to understand the principles first. Also, what's your use case for canceling DST? If you need a computer-friendly representation, the system clock (UTC) is already perfect. If you need a user-friendly one, you do need DSTs. (By the way, if you really need DST-free timezone definitions, GMT-14..GMT+12 are available for this purpose.)

Comment: @egmont You are correct. Ultimately, this is an attempt to appease a requirement that was not fully thought through. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56976824/2752503)